# execution of stored procedure in sql profiler

Tags: sql-server

I've got a stored procedure with an int output parameter. If I run SQL Server Profiler, execute the stored procedure via some .Net code, and capture the RPC:Completed event, the Text Data looks like this:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=13
exec spStoredProcedure @OutParam=@p1 output
select @p1
```

Why does it look like it's getting the value of the output parameter before executing the stored procedure?

I found an answer that it is `RPC:completed` event class. so it already know the result at that time. But I cant understand why exec statement is there, after completion of `RPC:completed` event.

Answer (score 1):

The RPC Completed TextData you see in the Profiler (or Extended Events) trace is just a rendering of the RPC request, not the actual statement that was executed by SQL Server. This facilitates copy/paste of the text into an SSMS window for ad-hoc execution as a SQL batch.

Since the actual output value is known after the RPC has completed, the trace text uses the actual value to initialize the parameter variable. It would probably be clearer it was initialized to NULL prior to execution.